# How to output a formatted excel document in Java

Tags: java, excel

I'm working on a project in Java where I need to output an excel document with non-standard cell colors and widths. I have always outputted to excel via a csv. Is there a way to add the rich formatting to the csv or is there another way? Thanks!

Comment: Try Apache POI https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Comment: FYI for future requests for software or libraries, Software Recs is the place to go:  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As noted, Apache POI _is_ very good.  [JXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net) may also be worth considering.